# Linking of Visual C++ project (VS 2010) results in the error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1073741515

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

Previously this Visual C++ project was run successfully in Visual Studio 2005
In Visual Studio 2010 I am getting the linking error, please, see below

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>Lib:
1>  mStaticLibr.vcxproj -> C:\Users\AlexN\workspace\ap\ap- 3a4857c51ff6\development\allProjects\Debug\mStaticLibr.lib
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\mStaticLibr.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\mStaticLibr.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:01:10.44
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: fnd_p, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Build started 7/20/2013 12:08:59 PM.
2>_PrepareForClean:
2>  Deleting file "Debug\fnd_p.lastbuildstate".
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Creating "Debug\fnd_p.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2>ClCompile:
2>  FND_P.CPP
2>Manifest:
2>  Deleting file "Debug\fnd_p.exe.embed.manifest".
```

> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(392,5): error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
>       2>
>       2>Build FAILED.

Comment: A Google search led me to an msdn forum post about a similar error code - it's not the exact one you have, but they fixed their problem by disable Whole Program Optimization. Any chance that helps?

Comment: That's exception code 0xc0000135, STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.  In other words, the link.exe program cannot start because it is missing a DLL that it needs to get the job done.  That's a pretty gross install problem.  Just in case, do check if you can get "Hello world" linked.  With the expectation that it will bomb with the exact same error code.  You'll next spin the re-install wheel of fortune.

Comment: Tried disabling Whole Program Optimization - did not help. Yes, got the same problem with "Hello World". By the way our admin installed VS 2010 - I do not have installation privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint about disabling Whole Program Optimization helped.  However, for this particular case one needs to set "Generate Manifest" as No in the Linker/Manifest File options

Comment: Appreciate explanation of down-voting

Comment: Probably people who needed a different answer, like changing the Visual Studio install to include "Tools and Windows SDK".

Comment: As I wrote, in this case I did not have the installation options.  The solution I found helped me a lot